# How to get single item from firebase realtime database?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a component and a service that are meant to work together to retrieve an item from my firebase realtime database.

The realtime database stores people and their firstname(fname) and lastname(lname).

From my component, "id" is retrieved from the URL, which is the unique id in firebase.
Then, my edit component references to the service to getSingleItem(this.id).
Here is a section from the component ts file:

```
constructor(
     private es: Service
){ }

ngOnInit() {
     // This code graps the "id" from the URL
     this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params["id"];
    });

    this.item = this.es.getSingleItem(this.id);
    console.log(this.item); //returns strange object
    console.log(this.item.fname);// shows as undefined.
    console.log(this.item.lname);//shows as undefined
    

    this.editForm = this.fb.group({
      fname: [null], //cant get this.item.fname (comes as undefined)
      lname: [null]  //cant get this.item.fname (comes as undefined)
    });
```

Then in my service, getSingleItem() looks like this:

```
constructor(
private fdb: AngularFireDatabase
){ }

getSingleItem(id: string) { 
      const itemPath =  `people/${id}`;
      this.item = this.fdb.list(itemPath);
      return this.item
    }
```

but back in the component, when I console.log(this.item) it returns a strange object that looks like this:
`{query: Reference, update: ƒ, set: ƒ, push: ƒ, remove: ƒ, …}`
with no traces of the actual data i want to be seen.

When i try to do `console.log(this.item.fname)` or `console.log(this.item.lname)` it comes as undefined.

How can I retrieve the item from the database properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to subscribe to the listener that `this.fdb.list(itemPath)` returns.

For example:

```
this.fdb.list(itemPath).valueChanges((value) => console.log(value));
```

Or if you need both the document ID and value:

```
this.fdb.list(itemPath).snapshotChanges((doc) => console.log(doc.id, doc.data()));
```

---

You may also need to use `doc` instead of `list`, since you're observing a single document.